# how to send message to both kafka channel and jdbc with spring integration?

Tags: jdbc, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We're trying to poll from a jdbc source, aggregate the messages, and then send the output of the aggregator to both a kafka stream and then a jdbcMessageHandler (to update the rows that we polled so that they are not polled again. It's actually a separate table). We're using the IntegrationFlow DSL. The polling and aggregating are working fine. The output to multiple outputs/sources/channels/handlers are what's not working.

Our current flow looks like this:

```
IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(), new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>(){
            @Override
            public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec) {
                sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec.poller(poller);
            }
        })

    .split()
    .transform((message)-> {
        // do our stuff; output is a simple POJO representing a single row from the db
    })
    .aggregate(aggregator -> aggregator) // details spared but it works fine; output is a larger POJO containing a collection of the row objects
    .channel(this.source.output()) // this goes to kafka
    .handle(jdbcMessageHandler()); // doesn't get here
```

Here is our polling source:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcPollingChannelAdapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource, this.properties.getQuery());
      jdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setSelectSqlParameterSource(createSqlParameterSource());

    return jdbcPollingChannelAdapter;
}
```

jdbcMessageHandler is simply this:

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
    return new JdbcMessageHandler(dataSource, this.properties.getUpdate());
}
```

this.output is simply this:

```
@Autowired
private Source source;
```

It is mapped via @EnableBinding(Source.class) to a kafka topic in our application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output: our.topic
```

Most of our properties are defined in an application.yml file, and we use these properties and Annotations instead of XMl configuration.

With the above, it write to kafka fine, but doesn't get to the jdbcMessageHandler.

I worked when I did this (after the aggregator):

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
                .subscribe(flow -> flow
                        .handle(jdbcMessageHandler()))
        )
.channel(this.source.output())
```

But this is the wrong order; we want to make sure the message is written to kafka first, then update the table that keeps track of what rows have been successfully polled.

The jdbcMessageHandler simply wraps an INSERT statement that uses values from the Message, so I assume there are various ways to do this. Is a jdbcOutboundGateway one way? It looks like that is intended to do another query and return a result to be further processed, which does not fit our use case.

It's also been suggested to use the polling to update, since we're using polling as our source. I looked into this. I don't think this will work either, because it appears to do the update immediately after polling, before the polling results are even processed, so it has the same problem with timing of doing the update before the final aggregated message is sent to kafka.

EDIT: I tried the answer below, so the current flow is this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
    IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(), new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>(){
                @Override
                public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec) {
                    sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec.poller(poller);
                }
            })

    .split()
    .transform((message)-> {
        // transform ResultSet; output is a simple POJO representing a single row from the db
    })
    .aggregate(aggregator -> aggregator) // details spared but it works fine; output is a larger POJO containing a collection of the row objects
    .publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                    .handle(this.source.output()))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                    .handle(jdbcMessageHandler()))
    );
}
```

and got the following error on startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [interface org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler] for method match: [public boolean org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.unsubscribe(org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler), public void org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.configureMetrics(org.springframework.integration.support.management.AbstractMessageChannelMetrics), public void org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setDatatypes(java.lang.Class[]), public org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.removeInterceptor(int), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException, public boolean org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.removeInterceptor(org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor), public java.lang.String org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.getComponentName(), public void org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setStatsEnabled(boolean), public void org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setMessageConverter(org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setMessageBuilderFactory(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilderFactory), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setComponentName(java.lang.String), public void org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setInterceptors(java.util.List), public final void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setPrimaryExpression(org.springframework.expression.Expression), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setChannelResolver(org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolver)]
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:113)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:499)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:226)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:37)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:985)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:964)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:950)
```

I debugged and stepped into that .handle() method on the IntegrationFlowDefinition and found that the passed object was converted to a DirectChannel somehow, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe both subflows to the pub/sub channel.

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                    .bridge(e -> e.id("bTO"))
                    .channel(this.source.output())
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                    .handle(jdbcMessageHandler()))
    )
```

You will need a `.bridge()` to bridge the pub/sub channel to the output channel.

Comment: Thanks, but this resulted in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [interface org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler] for method match: [public void org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setDatatypes(java.lang.Class[...really long stack trace

Comment: that error happened on startup when trying to instantiate the IntegrationFlow bean

Comment: Edit your question to show the current state of your code; also include any supporting code (such as `this.source`) as well as the stack trace.

Comment: I tried to include all relevant info. Let me know if you need more. Thank you, I appreciate you responding.

Comment: I need to see the actual flow definition as well as the source code (at least method signatures) for `this.source`.

Comment: I've updated it with the current flow, with your anser. There is no more info, source code, methods, etc. for this.source; it is a org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source interface as demonstrated in https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#_declaring_and_binding_channels

Comment: Sorry; missed that this was a Spring Cloud Stream app. You need a `.bridge()` - see the edit to my answer. Note that the kafka binder is async by default, unless you set `sync` on the kafka producer, you won't get an exception.

Comment: compiler is complaining that bridge() needs a Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<BridgeHandler>>; sorry I am pretty new to integrations and the lambdas only make it more confusing; I don't see any reference to a BridgeHandler on the integrations reference

Comment: Sorry; `.bridge()` with no arg was added in the upcoming Spring Integration 5; use `.bridge(e -> e.id("bTO"))`.

Comment: I added the `.bridge(e -> e.id("bTO"))` and am still getting the same 'ambiguous parameter type' IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Did you change `.handle()` back to `.channel()` as shown in my edit?

Comment: Nope, missed that. That fixed it. Thank you very much.